# How to run a page reload to all viewers

Tags: javascript, reload

I'm trying to do this:

- I have a page
- And 100 people are seeing this page now
- I would like to reload the page to all the viewers when i click in a button, for example:

The unique form i know is reload in each 5 minutes. But the people will have a delay to receive the information.

Like the Google disconnect (logout all the people logged when the password is changed). Or like the Twitter, where the user see the new tweets instantly.

How to do this?

Comment: I will answer your question with the same amount of regard you took asking it. Update the modal for all users.

Comment: I really didn't understand what you said. You was ironic?

Comment: Google is perhaps invalidating sessions, hence the next background request is triggering a foreground page request. If you want to do something like this you'll need some push notification approach like Comet or long polling, or web sockets if your user's browsers support it, and code a client-side method for receiving and acting on requests from the server to reload or redirect. Then your "button" triggers the server setting a message that is read by your socket monitoring background request streams. Rabbit, AMQP, pub/sub are all services or patterns for doing this.

Comment: Where i live, when you say using the exactly words that you used, this is interpreted as ironic. It means "You were disrespectful ...".

Comment: I'll search more about this Jared. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into web sockets (e.g. http://socket.io/ ) or if that's too complicated, just make the user page do an ajax request every 10 or 15 seconds to check if the page needs to reload. Depending on how many visitors you have and what resources your site use this could cause heavy load on the server.

Comment: Do you know some website using this tool? This is interesting.

Comment: I mostly see it in games or chat apps. You can find a short list in their github page https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Projects-using-Socket.IO
You can also find something like https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js which is used by Ratchet PHP websocket http://socketo.me/